# Turn pandas dataframe row in to a column based on unique IDs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape

I have a data frame similar to the one below. 'song obj' is actually a nested dictionary of various information about a song eg.

```
{data:{album:{album name:---, album id:---}},track{track name:---,track id:---}}
```

some playlists are very long so there are up to 400 columns, each labelled with an integer number.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"playlist id" : {0 : 8179, 1:8764, 2:8776},
                0 : {0:"song obj",1:"song obj",2:"song obj"},
                1: {0:"song obj",1:"song obj",2:"song obj"},
                2 : {0:"song obj",1:"song obj",2:"song obj"}   
               })
```

which looks like this:

```
>>>
    playlist  id rating 0           1           2
0   8179      3         song obj 1  song obj 2  song obj 3
1   8764      2         song obj 4  song obj 5  NaN
2   8776      4         song obj 6  song obj 7  song obj 8
```

I am trying to get the data frame above to look like this one, with all the 'song objects' vertical but next to their corresponding playlist number like the data frame below:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({
"playlist id": {0: 8179,1:8179,2:8179,3:8764,4:8764,
                5:8776,6:8776,7:8776},
"rating": {0:3, 1:3, 2:3, 3:2, 4:2, 5:4, 6:4, 7:4},
"song objects": {0:"song obj 1", 1:"song obj 2", 2:"song obj 3", 
                 3:"song obj 4", 4:"song obj 5",5:"song obj 6",
                 6:"song obj 7",7:"song obj 8"}
             })
>>>
    playlist id  rating song objects
  0 8179         3      song obj 1
  1 8179         3      song obj 2
  2 8179         3      song obj 3
  3 8764         2      song obj 4
  4 8764         2      song obj 5
  5 8776         4      song obj 6
  6 8776         4      song obj 7
  7 8776         4      song obj 8
```

I have tried using the `pd.wide_to_long` and also and `pd.melt` but so far I have had no luck. I have tried searching on stack exchange also but because I am new to programming/python/pandas I don't have the correct terminology to find what I need..please help!

Note: The reason is because eventually I want to 'unpack' the 'song object' into new columns. I think this will be possible with

```
df2=pd.concat([df2.drop(['song objects'], axis=1), df2['song objects'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
```

Comment: Is your source a JSON file?

Comment: Where does `rating` come from in your first `df`? Your code does not return the results you indicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to modify this slightly, as your example code doesn't produce the output you indicate, such as the `rating` column.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"playlist id" : {0 : 8179, 1:8764, 2:8776},
                0 : {0:"song obj",1:"song obj",2:"song obj"},
                1: {0:"song obj",1:"song obj",2:"song obj"},
                2 : {0:"song obj",1:"song obj",2:"song obj"}   
               })

pd.melt(df, id_vars = ['playlist id'], value_vars = [0, 1, 2])
```

Output:

```
    playlist id     variable    value
0   8179    0   song obj
1   8764    0   song obj
2   8776    0   song obj
3   8179    1   song obj
4   8764    1   song obj
5   8776    1   song obj
6   8179    2   song obj
7   8764    2   song obj
8   8776    2   song obj
```